# Understanding the definition of product of sets

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we are given a family of sets $\{ X_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A } $, my book the cartesian product of them as:

$$ \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} = \bigg\{ f: A \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} : f(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}, \alpha \in A \bigg\} $$

This definition is sort of hard to digest, so I was trying to think of it when $A = \{1,2 \} $, and expect this to coincide with the definition

$$ X_1 \times X_2 = \{ (x,y) : x \in X_1,  y \in X_2 \} $$

but as $A = \{1,2\}$ in the  definition above, we obtain

$$ \prod_{i \in \{1,2\}} X_i = \{ f: \{1,2 \} \to X_1 \cup X_2 : f(1) \in X_1, f(2) \in X_2 \}$$

which differs from the usual definition of Cartesian product of two sets. Are they different definitions?

Comment: The answer to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325778/a-question-on-the-generalization-of-cartesian-product) may be an interesting read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bijection $\varphi: \prod_{i \in \{1, 2\}}X_i \to X_1 \times X_2$, given by $\varphi(f) = (f(1), f(2))$.

Comment: how do you know It is bijective?

Comment: I wanted to leave this as an exercise to you. Try it. If you don't make progress with it, then ask a precise question. :-)

Comment: As for surjectivity, it seems obvious, but here is my solution: Pick any $(x,y) \in X_1 \times X_2 $. We can find $f: \{ 1,2 \} \to X_1 \cup X_2 $ such that $f(1) \in X_1 $ and $f(2) \in X_2 $, so if we put $x = f(1) $ and $y = f(2) $ we are done. It this a correct?

Comment: It would be clearer if you say "define $f: \{1, 2\} \to X_1 \cup X_2$ via $f(1) = x$ and $f(2) = y$". But it seems correct. So, do you also know why it is injective?

Comment: but, I am still stuck on the injectivity part. Can you help me ?

Comment: What can you say about functions $f, g : \{1, 2\} \to X_1 \cup X_2$ with $\varphi(f) = \varphi(g)$? By definition this means $(f(1), f(2)) = (g(1), g(2))$, so by definition of tuples... . Can you proceed?

Comment: So, we've defined a function $\psi:X_1\times X_2\to \prod_i=1^2X_i$. Show that it is the *inverse* of $\varphi$.

Comment: Thanks Leon, it was so obvious the injectivity part.

Comment: @easy: This is, I think, one of the many instances where the easiest way to prove something is a bijection is to write down its inverse.

Answer (score 3):

The definition is hard to digest because it is omitting an essential quantifier (and instead abusing colons and commas to express distinctions that they can't possibly carry to a reader who doesn't *already* know what is meant by the definition). It should be

$$\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} = \bigg\{ f: A \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} \mathrel{\Bigg|} \forall \alpha\in A\,\bigl[f(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}\bigr] \bigg\}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_\alpha$ be sets, indiced by a set $A$. 
The product set $\prod_{\alpha\in A} X_\alpha$ is defined to contain all the '*sequences*' $(\dots,\, x_\alpha,\, \dots)_{\alpha\in A}$ with $x_\alpha\in X_\alpha$.

Now, what exactly do we mean by these 'sequences'? 
Well, these can be caught as *functions* defined on $A$ that assign the '*coordinate*' $x_\alpha$ to any $\alpha\in A$.

In this view, it is clear that the original definition $X_1\times X_2$ is *essentially* the same as $\prod_{\alpha\in\{1,2\}}X_\alpha$, however, literally they are different sets.

(And one more side note: the definition of $A\times B$ is necessary to define *functions*, so there is no way to start right away with the more general definition of products of sets.)

Comment: I am confused when you say that the elements of $\prod X_{\alpha } $ are of the form $(...., x_{\alpha},....) $ with $x_{\alpha} \in X_{\alpha} $. How is this the case?