# Inconsistent set theoretic notation for expressing function/sequence spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

If for any sets $X$ and $Y$ one writes $Y^{X}$ to denote the set of all functions $f:X\to Y$ then shouldn't the set of all sequences with entries in a field $\mathbb{F}$ be given by the expression $S=\bigcup_{f\in \mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\{f(k)\}$ as expanding the Cartesian product of singletons in $S$ gives the following:

$$S=\bigcup_{f\in \mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\{f(k)\}=\bigcup_{f\in \mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}}\{f(1)\}\times \{f(2)\}\times\{f(3)\}\times \cdots=\bigcup_{f\in \mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}}\{(f(1),f(2),f(3),\cdots)\}\\=\{(f(1),f(2),f(3),\cdots):f\in \mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}\}=\{(f(1),f(2),f(3),\cdots):\text{For all functions }f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{F}\}$$

Yet according to various responses/answers on this website as well as Wikipedia people refer to the set of all sequences with entries in 
 $\mathbb{F}$ as simply $\mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space

How can this make sense? If every element of the set $f\in \mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a function from $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{F}$ which in no way corresponds to a sequence, much less anything resembling say a tuple of elements in $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325778/

Answer (score 4):

"A function... in no way corresponds to a sequence" - on the contrary, a sequence is nothing else but a function with domain $\Bbb N$.  The notation
$$a_0\,,\ a_1\,,\ a_2\,,\ldots$$
is merely another way of writing
$$a(0)\,,\ a(1)\,,\ a(2)\,,\ldots\ .$$

Comment: I don't understand if the domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and the codomain is $\mathbb{F}$ shouldn't you be mapping individual natural numbers to elements of the field. Can you specify what input is mapping to what sequence, I don't quite understand what is being said.

Comment: I assume you agree that $f(x)=x^2+2x+3$ defines a function?  This means that $0$ maps to $3$ and $1$ maps to $6$ and $2$ maps to $11$ and so on.  Well, the sequence means that $0$ maps to $a_0$ and $1$ maps to $a_1$ and $2$ maps to $a_2$ and so on.

Comment: Yes but those are individual maps, not the entire tuple. Thus we might have $f(0)=a_0$ and $f(1)=a_1$ etc. for each $f\in \mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}$ but the notation used by others necessitates that $f$ itself be a tuple. Am I missing something? If $\mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}$  is the set of all functions from $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{F}$ by the first notation, then in order for it to be consistent with the second notation that must mean each function is itself a tuple, correct?

Comment: Well, what do you say a sequence is? - please don't say "a list" because that is just another word, not an explanation.

Comment: Defined recursively using Kuratowski's representation for ordered pairs as nested sets.

Comment: That's how a (specific?) sequence is defined, but what actually is the meaning of the word "sequence"?

Comment: I'm not understanding the question, I'm sorry I'm just trying to make everything formal. And the first notation used doesn't seem to be compatible with the second notation. Should I update my question with an inductive definition of elements in the sequence using Kuratowski's construction and a successor function.

Comment: That's exactly the point - if you are trying to make everything formal, you need a formal definition of what the word "sequence" means.

Comment: In terms of the recursive definition involving nested sets, I don't understand are you asking about the semantics of what a "set" is? I thought that was taken as a primitive? Like suppose $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{F}$ and I define a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(n)=n^2$. Now we have $f\in \mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}$ but how is this a sequence? I don't understand, maybe you are using some other convention or notation which is causing further confusion? Maybe I'm just not seeing something, I don't know.

Comment: The usual definition of a sequence is "a function with domain $\Bbb N$" - or possible variations to allow starting from $1$ instead of $0$ and similar things.  The function $f(n)=n^2$ is really just another way of writing the sequence $0,1,4,9,16,\ldots\,$.  I'm afraid I don't understand the other issues you are raising.

Comment: But wouldn't you write something like $[f(n)]_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ to indicate its ranging over those values? I mean a sequence shouldn't have a free variable right? Whereas a stand alone function would? Or no?

Comment: @user3865391 You can't define *infinite* sequences as "recursively nested pairs" (unless you are going to start talking about coinduction). However, you can for finite sequences. Let $[n]$ be a set with $n$ elements. A function $[n]\to X$ is not an $n$-tuple of $X$s, i.e. an element of $X^n$, but there is a *bijection* between $n$-tuples and functions $[n]\to X$. You should spell this out. To generalize to the infinite case it is simpler to use the functional perspective.

Comment: @DerekElkins I was going to define it recursively like with the Von Neumann construction of $\mathbb{N}$ using a bunch of nested sets. Though by your last comment, then are you saying yes the notation is ambiguous (perhaps not up to isomorphism/bijection but still not equal).

Comment: @user3865391 You can pun $X^n$, the set of $n$-tuples with $X$s, with $X^{[n]}$, the set of functions $[n]\to X$ - the notation was not an accident - but they are technically different sets. Like David said though, an *infinite* sequence of $X$s *is* most commonly defined as simply a function $\mathbb N\to X$. There is no other good, handy option, so there is no other notion of infinite sequence to be in contradiction with.

Comment: @Derek Elkins Wouldn't it be more natural following your first notation to then have the exponent be $\aleph_{0}$ so it would equate with the standard definition for finite cardinals i.e. natural numbers?

Comment: @user3865391 If you like. It's not particularly important. There are many, many ways set-theoretic definitions can be technically different from each other in ways that don't matter. For example, for the set of 3-tuples of $X$, $X^3$, do I mean left or right nested pairs? Also, what *exact* definition of "pair" am I using? Each decision leads to a different set. These are distinctions we generally don't care about. The notion of [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property) in category theory provides a means of specifying the properties we do care about.